# Changing order in geom_col on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data that look like this

```
structure(list(country = c("CHN", "CHN", "CHN", "JPN", "JPN", 
"JPN", "KAZ", "KAZ", "KAZ", "KOR", "KOR", "KOR", "SYR", "SYR", 
"SYR", "THA", "THA", "UZB", "UZB", "VIE", "VIE"), Final_Medal = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("GOLD", "SILVER", "BRONZE"), class = "factor"), 
    n = c(17L, 28L, 15L, 15L, 9L, 18L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 4L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -21L
), groups = structure(list(country = c("CHN", "JPN", "KAZ", "KOR", 
"SYR", "THA", "UZB", "VIE"), .rows = structure(list(1:3, 4:6, 
    7:9, 10:12, 13:15, 16:17, 18:19, 20:21), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

For the structur of the final medal, I have change it to factor and give it a new level.

```
medal_records$Final_Medal<- factor(medal_records$Final_Medal, levels= c("GOLD","SILVER","BRONZE"))
```

However when I plot it in ggplot the bar order are still the same in BRONZE, Silver and Gold, and I want Gold on the top followed by silver and bronze. Here's my code

```
mr <- ggplot(medal_records )+
  geom_col(aes(x = n, y = country, fill = Final_Medal), position = "dodge", width = 0.7) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 35)) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev) +
  #scale_fill_manual(values = pal_mk[4:5]) +
  labs(
    title = "Medal Records",
    subtitle = "Top 8 country with the most medals in internationl event"
  ) +
  theme(
    legend.position = c(0.875, 0.5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By `desc`,

```
ggplot(medal_records )+
  geom_col(aes(x = n, y = country, group = desc(Final_Medal), fill = Final_Medal), position = "dodge", width = 0.7) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 35)) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev) +
  #coord_flip() +
  #scale_fill_manual(values = pal_mk[4:5]) +
  labs(
    title = "Medal Records",
    subtitle = "Top 8 country with the most medals in internationl event"
  ) +
  theme(
    legend.position = c(0.875, 0.5))
```

[image: desc]